# How MYSQL check MD5 password

Tags: java, mysql, md5

I have established a MySQL connection with java. I also have Hashed my Password with MD5.

How do you usually send encrypted MD5 Password to mysql?

I do it like below but false, I put the already hashed password to SQL query. MySQL cant read it.

```
String Password = "890621";

//hash value after "890621" being hash MD5. 
String newHashPassword = "a8ae0ba1adf92c69fd33b1c6d4c2376f";  

if (stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_name = 'James' AND password=" 
    + newHashPassword)) {
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();      
}
```

Can anyone show me sample code of how to sent md5 password to MySQL?

Comment: can you show us what in your database? `select * from table;`

Comment: Like you would any other String, this of course assumes that the value in the database is also a MD5 hash. But you really should use a PreapredStatement...

Comment: What is your question that is srsly unclear.. The way you are sending the value are correct. You perform a MD5 encryption on the frontend part and then pass the value to MySQL querry as a part of string.

Comment: Rugal sorry i cant reveal the database but the content inside can not be the error. Im sure it is because i actually cant sent MD5 password directly to mysql

Comment: [Read this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-md5-hashing-salting-password/), it might help you

Comment: in the code as posted you never actually appended the hash value to the string.......

Comment: Affe you are right, i put the wrong code, i think i should post a new question. thanks everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guy for helping me out.

Actually, like mad MadProgrammer said, I just need to put the MD5 password as string inside mysql query.

```
String Password = "890621";

//hash value after "890621" being hash MD5. 

String newHashPassword = "a8ae0ba1adf92c69fd33b1c6d4c2376f";

 if (stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_name = 'James' AND password= '" + newHashPassword+"'");

hexString.toString()
```

Actually I just have syntax error. Thanks everybody.